# use of "over" with "distance"

Tags: sentence-construction, spoken-english

I usually say:

> I travel a long distance to get to work.

Today I saw:

> It travels **over a long distance.**

I didn't find any information about **over a long distance.**

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Farlex](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/travel+over) has "travel over", perhaps that will help.

Answer (score 1):

"**[over](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/over)**" (see definition B1) - across from one side to the other, especially by going up and then down.

Basically over forms a path in the shape of an arc from here to there.

- Carrying heavy load over long distances is difficult.

Mostly met in context related to transportation across distances, probably those which include slopes.

Answer (score -1):

"Travels over ..." will usually be referring to an object, such as a train or a bus, which is travelling over/on a road or railway.

For an individual, while the travel is still arguably still reliant on roads and rails, the emphasis is on the journey as a whole, so conventionally 'over' is not used.